# Is it possible to measure time of all Spring managed transactions with @Transactional?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, transactions

I would like to measure time of transacactions managed by Spring with `JpaTJpaTransactionManager`/`PlatformTransactionManager` to detect long pending transactions and warn some listener about that condition.

I could use aspect on `@Transactional` methods but due to transaction propagation it's not a good way to detect when exact transaction is started or finished.

It would be good to something like transaction listener with access to start/finish events together with some bean name of object starting the trasaction or just a stack trace

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use TransactionSynchronizationManager inside annotated method:

```
TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(new TransactionSynchronization(){

       long startTime;

       void beforeCommit() {
           startTime = System.nanoTime();
       }
       void afterCommit(){
           System.out.println("Transaction time: " + (System.nanoTime() - startTime));
       }
});
```

Track all transactions with aspect:

```
 @Aspect
 class TransactionAspect extends TransactionSynchronizationAdapter {

   @Before("@annotation(org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional)")
   public void registerTransactionSyncrhonization() {
       TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(this);

   }

   ThreadLocal<Long> startTime = new ThreadLocal<>();

   void beforeCommit() {
       startTime.set(System.nanoTime());
   }
   void afterCommit(){
       System.out.println("Transaction time: " + (System.nanoTime() - startTime.get()));
   }
}
```

Comment: Uvoted but I actually mean general transaction mesurement to track slow transactions, not explicitly tracke each single transaction. Edited question.

Comment: @PiotrMüller Use aspects.

Comment: The current suggestion is wrong as it uses `beforeCommit` instead of measuring from start of transaction.

Comment: The `TransactionSynchronizationAdapter` interface does not provide a `beginTransaction` or `getTransaction` to step in. One could move the start time measurement inside `registerTransactionSynchronization`. But then one would measure the whole runtime of the Transactional annotated method instead of begin to end of transaction.

Comment: Be careful because `beforeCommit` doesn't work for rollback cases. For it better use `beforeCompletion` method

Comment: I don't see how `@Before` can work - since before the transaction is defined there is no transaction active so `TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(this);` should fail. I had to se `@After` in my code.

Comment: nvm my comment above I had no idea what I was talking about LOL

Answer (score 1):

You may consider implementing a class which implements `ApplicationListener<E extends ApplicationEvent>` and perform measuring there. Something like this:

```
@Component
public class TransactionListener implements ApplicationListener<Neo4jDataManipulationEvent> {

   private Long transactionStart;
   private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TransactionListener.class);

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(Neo4jDataManipulationEvent event) {
        if (event instanceof BeforeSaveEvent) {
            transactionStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
        if (event instanceof AfterSaveEvent) {
            log.debug("Transaction time in ms: ", System.currentTimeMillis() - transactionStart);
            log.debug("Source: ", event.getSource());
        }
    }
```

For JPA you may consider implementing a similar solution (according to [this tutorial](https://alexandre-gama.com/2014/03/23/entity-listeners-and-callback-methods-jpa/)):

```
public class LogListener {

    private Long transactionStart;

    @PrePersist
    @PreUpdate
    @PreRemove
    private void before(Object object) {
        transactionStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    @PostPersist
    @PostUpdate
    @PostRemove
    private void after(Object object) {
        System.out.println("Transaction time in ms: ", System.currentTimeMillis() - transactionStart);
        System.out.println("Source: ", object.getClass());
    }

}
```

You will need to annotate your entity classes which instances are persisted to the DB with `@EntityListeners(LogListener.class)` after that.

Comment: Does JPA emits such transactional events?

Comment: @PiotrMüller I've edited my answer. Let me know if this will work for you. However, idk how to measure reading transaction time this way.

Comment: Upvotes as some solution but original question regards transactional mechanism, so it should span transaction time and also handle such transations like for .createNativeQuery or even JDBC if only are spanned by JPA transaction manager.

Comment: It's a really bad practice to measure time with `System.currentTimeMillis()`, use monotonic `System.nanoTime()` instead