# spring @Transactional time count

Tags: spring, transactions, aop, druid

## Hi everyone,

I have a method with @transactional annotation.I use druid to monitor the time spent.And I want to see the time that the transaction spends.So what should I do to achieve it.
This is the method example:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, isolation = Isolation.DEFAULT, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public void test(String data) throws Exception {}
```

## Please,thanks for your help. Have a good day.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40071088/is-it-possible-to-measure-time-of-all-spring-managed-transactions-with-transact

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to measure time of all Spring managed transactions with @Transactional?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40071088/is-it-possible-to-measure-time-of-all-spring-managed-transactions-with-transact)

Comment: thanks ,have a good day.